# Retrieving Header Information from Web Service using Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, http-headers, digest-authentication

I am currently stuck trying to retrieve the www-authenticate header information on the mobile device from a WCF web service.  It is an android mobile app built on the phonegap platform (so i am using javascript heavily).

I tried testing the app on a few different browsers.  ie7 and safari allow me to retrieve the information with no problem.  However firefox, chrome, AND unfortunately the android device do not allow me to get the information.   Chrome and Firefox complain about cross-site ajax calls… and the phone just freezes up when the function is called.

I am pretty sure that it is not related to cross site ajax issues because mobile -> webservice is not considered cross-site… I can successfully retrieve header information from a regular website like www.google.com.  Does anybody have any tips to point me in the right direction?

The following is my code:

```
function getAuthInfo(){    
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('HEAD', "http://foo.com/messages/userreg", false);
    req.send();
    alert(req.getAllResponseHeaders());
    alert(req.getResponseHeader("Www-Authenticate"));
}
```